# Function expects array to be string, convert?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, string

I get this error:

> Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in bla bla

This is the code that produces it:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'Napadi') {

    $igralec_ime = $_SESSION['username'];
    $igralec = array (
                      'ime'         => $igralec_ime,
                      'napad'   => prikazi_stat('ofe',$igralec_ime),
                      'obramba' => prikazi_stat('def',$igralec_ime),
                      'curhp'       => prikazi_stat('curhp',$igralec_ime)
                     );

    $monster_ime = $_POST['monster'];
    $monster = array (
                      'ime'         => $monster_ime,
                      'napad'   => prikazi_monster_stat('ofe',$monster_ime),
                      'obramba' => prikazi_monster_stat('def',$monster_ime),
                      'curhp'       => prikazi_monster_stat('maxhp',$monster_ime)
                     );       

    $combat = array();
    $turns = 0;     
    while($igralec['curhp'] > 0 && $monster['curhp'] > 0) {

        if($turns % 2 != 0) {
            $napadalec = &$monster;
            $branilec = &$igralec; } 
        else {
            $napadalec = &$igralec;
            $branilec = &$monster; }

        $damage = 0;    
        if($napadalec['napad'] > $branilec['obramba']) {
            $damage = $napadalec['napad'] - $branilec['obramba']; }

        $branilec['curhp'] -= $damage;
        $combat[$turns] = array(
            'napadalec' =>  $napadalec['ime'],
            'branilec'  =>  $branilec['ime'],
            'damage'    =>  $damage
                               )

        $turns++; }

$_SESSION['monster'] = $monster;
```

Above code puts variable $monster in an array as you can see, now when this page redirects to my view page and tries to update a function `update_save($igralec_ime, 'gozd', $monster);` I get the above warning. I know this is because the page returns a bunch of monster variables like so:

```
Matic napade Velikanski komar in mu napravi poškodbe za 2 točk zdravja

Velikanski komar napade Matic in mu napravi poškodbe za 1 točk zdravja

Matic napade Velikanski komar in mu napravi poškodbe za 2 točk zdravja

Velikanski komar napade Matic in mu napravi poškodbe za 1 točk zdravja
```

etc. But I don't know how to fix it. Should I convert this output array back to string?

EDIT: code with problematic function

```
function update_save($igralec_name, $lokacija, $monster_name = null) {
ustvari_save($igralec_name, $lokacija, $monster_name);
$query = sprintf("UPDATE igralec_save SET lokacija = '%s', monster_name = '%s' WHERE igralec_name = '%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($lokacija),
    mysql_real_escape_string($monster_name),
    mysql_real_escape_string($igralec_name));
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: There's no `mysql_real_escape_string` anywhere in the code we can see and we don't know what you're doing with those variables. Fact is you're trying to feed an array into `mysql_real_escape_string`, which simply doesn't work.

Comment: Show the code where the error occurs. It's not included in your sample and not related to it

Comment: @deceze I know feedin an array into mysql_real_escape_string doesn't work I am asking how can I get a variable our of my array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$monster` is an array and `mysql_real_escape_string` as the name implies, takes a string, you must pass it a string.

Since the function takes a `$monster_name`, perhaps you need to take that from the `$monster` array?

Something like (without any idea of your code, just as an example, do not copy and paste :) ):

```
update_save($igralec_ime, 'gozd', $monster['ime']);
```

Comment: Exactly! I overlooked such a simple solution, you don't need to take the array apart just select the variable of the array like that. I need to start overcomplicating things